# Does assigning values to static member variables in a constructor cause any problems? (JAVA)

Tags: java

I am running two client programs. The clients need access to a common database.

I am using a Java class with static member variables as the database. Both clients have their own instance of the database class. I believe that the database's static member variables should, if modified, carry the changes to both database instances in the clients. Is this correct?

Additionally, the database's default constructor adds values to its static member variables. Is this bad practice, if so, why?

Comment: Please provide some code examples and more information what database you use and where the clients run. Do you have two different Java applications that run on the same machine or do you have one application that runs on two machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` variables don't below to the `instance` of the class but to the class itself. Therefore both of your `Client` instances will be able to use the database without problems.

However, because they belong to the *class* and not the *instance*, attempting to access them before an instance has been created will cause your database variables to still be `null` and throw an exception if not caught.

---

Implementing a `Singleton` pattern might be a better way to solve your problem since the class instance and connection will be created when you try to access them if they don't exist yet.

Example:

```
class Database {

    private static Database theInstance;

    private Database() {
        // Create connections here and stuff
    }

    public static Database getInstance() {
        if (theInstance == null) {
            theInstance = new Database();
        }
        return theInstance;
    }

}
```

Then you can access your database like this:

```
Database.getInstance().doQueryStuff(); // doQueryStuff is just an example of a method call.
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If it`s the same database, then you can/should Run a static reference to the database. You will save on memory a lot by making the database reference static.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it helps